# UI tabs 302 redirection

Tags: jquery, http, jquery-ui-tabs, redirect

I use UI tabs with the following ajaxOptions :

```
    **$("#ss-tabs-1, #ss-tabs-4, #ss-tabs-5").tabs({
        cache: false,
        ajaxOptions: {
            cache: false,
            error: function (xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                    // how do I test to handle the HTTP code 302 ? (xhr.status contains 0 here and xhr.responseText is empty!)
                if ((xhr.status == 301) || (xhr.status == 302) || (xhr.status == 303) || (xhr.status == 304) || (xhr.status == 305) || (xhr.status == 306) || (xhr.status == 307) || (xhr.status == 308)) {
                    // how do I redirect to the redirection url
                }
                else {
                    $(anchor.hash).html("Error ...<br><br>URL : " + ??? + "<br><br>Error Code : " + xhr.status + "<br>" + xhr.responseText);
                }
            }
        }
    });**
```

My aim is to handle the HTTP code 302 which indicates a redirection. This HTTP code is handled as an error by UI tabs, but it is actually a redirection. As I debug with firebug, i see the redirection url in the HTTP response header. How can i redirect to that url instead of displaying an error ?

Many thanks

mike